# How to find the next index of a charachter in python list

Tags: python

I was dealing with python list and I want to find the next index of the recurring character in the list how can I accomplish that

```
country = ['Beekeeper', 'Fly', 'Hornet']


pickedCountry = random.choice(country)
let the pickedCountry = 'Beekeeper'
print(pickedCountry .index('e'),)
```

it print out only 1

Comment: Instead of randomly choosing word, you can randomly choosing number as index. By the picked number you will know the corresponding word and the next index

Comment: Do you want to find the next index of the recurring character from the whole `list` or from a single `object` (`string` in this case) in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
pickedCountry = 'Beekeeper'
last_index = 0
while last_index < len(pickedCountry):
    current_index = pickedCountry.index('e', last_index)
    print(current_index)
    last_index = current_index + 1
```

```py
pickedCountry = 'Beekeeper'
last_index = 0
while last_index < len(pickedCountry):
    try:
        current_index = pickedCountry.index('e', last_index)
    except ValueError:
        break
    print(current_index)
    last_index = current_index + 1
```

Comment: It throws error for example if you enter "e" and then "b" throws value error